# CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

Used `CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout` class  (https://github.com/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout) in my `UICollectionView`. It worked in `iOS7` by using `Swift2.3` . After updating to `Swift3`, it failed. The **Error** message is following.

> Uncaught exception: layout attributes for supplementary item at index path (< NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) changed from < CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout: 0x7f825bea4550> indexPath: {0, 0} zIndex: 1024 valid: YES kind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader to < CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout: 0x7f825becd510> indexPath: {0, 0}

**My code is following.**

```
let flowLayout = CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout()
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height+statusBarHeight() ,width: screenWidth,  height: screenHeight-(self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height+statusBarHeight())), collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)    

self.collectionView?.register(CollectionParallaxHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: CSStickyHeaderParallaxHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "parallaxHeader")

self.headerNib = UINib(nibName: "CSParallaxHeader", bundle: nil)
self.collectionView.register(self.headerNib, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: CSStickyHeaderParallaxHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header")

fileprivate var layout : CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout? {
    return self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout
}

func onParallaxHeadered(_ count:Int)
{
    if count == 0
    {
        self.layout?.parallaxHeaderReferenceSize = CGSize(width: getScreenWidth(), height: 0)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let view = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "parallaxHeader", for: indexPath) as! CollectionParallaxHeader

    return view
}
```

I have no idea how solve this problem. Does anyone give some suggestions? **Thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout/issues/144).

The code is

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        self.collectionView?.isPrefetchingEnabled = false
    } else {
        //Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have rolled back the version of xcode to 7.3. When I finish my work, I will try your suggestion.